# Alfresco javascript get custom DataList

Tags: javascript, alfresco, datalist

I've created a custom datalist and put some values on it. Now I try to get data values within a script that will be triggered by a rule. 
So far, I've trouble to get the custom datalist named `test` with this code:

```
var site = siteService.getSite(document.siteShortName);
var dataLists = site.getContainer("datalists");
var listCompany = dataLists.childByNamePath("test");
```

It seems that its return a null object but I can't figure it out why, I tried with

```
"dataLists", 
"datalists" and 
"data-lists"
```

but still null object... 
**Edit:** After looking int he solr log, I have an error that says that Model tracking failed NamespaceException. Something like my model has already been defined previously

**Second question:** How can I acces to the data inside the datalist? Is getElementById() will work?

`test` dataList is like:

```
'test'  
  field1: name, 
  field2: company, 
  field3:number, 
  field4: number2
```

Comment: can you put some datalists value?

Comment: the datalist contents 4 text fields

Comment: post some sample here for reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope the below script will help you to resolve your datalist issue.

```
var site = siteService.getSite(document.siteShortName);
var dataListsContainer = site.getContainer("datalists");
var dataLists = dataListsContainer.getChildren();

logger.log("Data List length : " + dataLists.length);
for(var x=0;x<dataLists.length;x++)
{
    var dataList = dataLists[x]; //Get the current data list        
    var props = dataList.getProperties(); //Read the data list properties
    var title = props["cm:title"]; //read the datalist's title property
    logger.log("Data List title : " + title);

    if (title.indexOf("<data_list_title_goes_here>") > -1){ //check whether it's the required data list or not

        var dataListItems = dataList.getChildren(); //get the all datalistitems
        logger.log("Total dataListItems : " + dataListItems.length +" for " + title);
        for(var y = 0;y<dataListItems.length;y++) //Iterate all the datalistitems one by one
        {
            var dataListItem = dataListItems[y];
            var dataListItemProps = dataListItem.getProperties();    //Read all the properties of the current datalistitem      
            logger.log(dataListItemProps["namespace:propertyname"]); //read your custom property here
            logger.log(dataListItemProps["namespace:propertyname"]); //read your custom property here
            logger.log(dataListItemProps["namespace:propertyname"]); //read your custom property here
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer that's really helps me!!! :)  This morning I'll try to make something like you did and reading your code I'll understand my mistake, I didn't call get children so that's why it always give a null exception.

Comment: I've just improved my code with yours and it works great!! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: How can i get only customized datalist which is created by user using .xml file instead of user interface?

Comment: Sanjay, i hope it will be very similar. Share your model details and will help. Basically you should use,dataListItemProps["namespace:propertyname"] to read the property values and let me know, if it is not helping you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Server side javascript, getElementById() won't work and this is for client side javascript.

Let me try with my custom datalist and will update you.
In mean time, can you please share, alfresco.log & solr.log file errors?

Comment: Actually the error I had in solr log was just a mistake I made when writing the uri of my datalist