# Alfresco javascript get custom DataList's properties

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I have written one rule(execute script) on datalist, so that whenever any new item is added, it should send an email to the respective user.

In email I want to add custom properties value e.g. `employee_first_name`

I've tried to get datalist using

```
var dataLists = siteName.getContainer("dataLists");
```

But it gives an error as follows:

> `"getContainer" method is not available.`

The script given in  [Alfresco javascript get custom DataList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056403/alfresco-javascript-get-custom-datalist) works perfectly in Javascript console.

Comment: Try fetching the site with that name first, then fetch the datalist on the site not the site name?

Comment: I am able to find the site name using

`var siteName = document.siteShortName;`

and for finding the datalist

`var dataListContainer = "dataLists";
var dataLists = siteName.getContainer("dataLists");`

For the above line it gives error like 

`TypeError: Cannot find function getContainer in object hardik-test.`

Comment: Tried with `var dataLists = siteName.childByNamePath("dataLists");`  

Getting the similar error like `can not find function childByNamePath()`

Comment: That's still only the name of the site! You need the object for the site itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your siteName variable is probably a string, which does not have a method called "getContainer". That's why you are seeing that message.

Here's a code snippet that fetches the data list container object given a site ID (site short name):

```
var siteId = "jtp-test-site-1";
var siteInfo = siteService.getSite(siteId);
var dataLists = siteInfo.getContainer("dataLists");
print(dataLists.name);
```

Notice the use of the built-in root-scoped object, siteService, that fetches the site info for a given site.

You can run that in the JavaScript Console and it will output the name of that folder, which is "datalists".